# how to differentiate these two xml tags with childnodes

Tags: php, xml

i have two tags in my sample xml as below,

```
 <EmailAddresses>2</EmailAddresses>

 <EmailAddresses>
        <string>Allen.Patterson01@fantasyisland.com</string>
         <string>Allen.Patterson12@fantasyisland.com</string>
 </EmailAddresses>
```

how to differentiate these two xml tags based on the childnodes that means how to check that first tag has no childnodes and other one has using DOM php

Comment: You can use an attribute. Your actual script create a new XML or it modify an existing XML? Can you please show your actual code?

Comment: actually i want to differentiate them with haschildNodes() in php but  both are treating as same...

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will meet your requirement. Just copy,paste and run it. And change/add logic whatever you want.

```
<?php
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<email>
 <EmailAddresses>2</EmailAddresses>

 <EmailAddresses>
        <string>Allen.Patterson01@fantasyisland.com</string>
         <string>Allen.Patterson12@fantasyisland.com</string>
 </EmailAddresses>
</email>
XML;   

$email = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);    
foreach ($email as $key => $value) {
    if(count($value)>1) {
        var_dump($value);
        //write your logic to process email strings
    } else {
        var_dump($value);
        // count of emails
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `->getElementsByTagName( 'string' )`:

```
foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'EmailAddresses' ) as $node )
{
    if( $node->getElementsByTagName( 'string' )->length )
    {
        // Code for <EmailAddresses><string/></EmailAddresses>
    }
    else
    {
        // Code for <EmailAddresses>2</EmailAddresses>
    }
}
```

`2` is considered as `<EmailAddresses>` child node, so in your XML `->haschildNodes()` returns always `True`.

You have this problem due your weird XML structure conception.
If you don't have particular reason to maintain this XML syntax, I suggest you to use only one tag:

```
<EmailAddresses count="2">
    <string>Allen.Patterson01@fantasyisland.com</string>
    <string>Allen.Patterson12@fantasyisland.com</string>
</EmailAddresses>
```

Answer (score 0):

Xpath allows you to do that.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<xml>
  <EmailAddresses>2</EmailAddresses>
  <EmailAddresses>
    <string>Allen.Patterson01@fantasyisland.com</string>
    <string>Allen.Patterson12@fantasyisland.com</string>
  </EmailAddresses>
</xml>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('number(//EmailAddresses[not(*)])')
);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//EmailAddresses/string') as $address) {
  var_dump($address->textContent);
}
```

Output:

```
float(2)
string(35) "Allen.Patterson01@fantasyisland.com"
string(35) "Allen.Patterson12@fantasyisland.com"
```

### The Expressions

Fetch the first `EmailAddresses` node without any element node child as a number.

- Select any `EmailAddresses` element node:
  `//EmailAddresses`
- That does not contain another element node as child node:
  `//EmailAddresses[not(*)]`
- Cast the first of the fetched `EmailAddresses` nodes into a number:
  `number(//EmailAddresses[not(*)])`

Fetch the `string` child nodes of the `EmailAddresses` element nodes.

- Select any `EmailAddresses` element node:
  `//EmailAddresses`
- Get their `string` child nodes:
  `//EmailAddresses/string`

In you example the first `EmailAddresses` seems to be duplicate information and stored in a weird way. Xpath can count nodes, too. The expression `count(//EmailAddresses/string)` would return the number of nodes.